# Undefined offset: 1 in php code

Tags: php, arrays

When I ran this below mentioned code, I got error as:

```
Undefined offset:1 for $productSize = $product[1];//pack size.
```

I am not able to get the data from database. It returns null array.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('callingapp') or die('no connection');
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $currentDate       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        /* Convert into sql time */
        $currentDate       = strtotime($currentDate);
        $currentDateTime   = time_php2sql($currentDate);
        // Get data
        $currentUserId     = isset($_POST['id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) : ""; //TelecallerId
        $callerId          = isset($_POST['callerid']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['callerid']) : ""; //id of lead /student
        $status            = isset($_POST['status']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']) : ""; //status new call,follow up ,schedule
        $notes             = isset($_POST['notes']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']) : ""; //comments
        $callstatus        = isset($_POST['callstatus']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['callstatus']) : ""; //answered/notanswered
        $callstatus        = strtolower($callstatus);
        $callstatus        = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $callstatus);
        $answered          = isset($_POST['answered']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['answered']) : ""; //answer status if call status is answered
        $not_answer        = isset($_POST['not_answer']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['not_answer']) : ""; //notanswer status if call status is notanswered
        $didnotlikestatus  = isset($_POST['didnotlikestatus']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['didnotlikestatus']) : ""; //didnot like status if call status is answered and did not like
        $datePost          = isset($_POST['date']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']) : "";
        /* Convert into sql time */
        $dates             = strtotime($datePost);
        $date              = time_php2sql($dates); //convert it into unix format
        $datetimetotinsert = isset($_POST['dateTime']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateTime']) : ""; //Call later date and time 
        /* Convert into sql time */
        $time              = strtotime($datetimetotinsert);
        $dateTime          = time_php2sql($time); //convert it into unix format
        $OrderDate         = isset($_POST['todayDateTime']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todayDateTime']) : ""; //order date
        $productnameorder  = isset($_POST['productnameorder']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productnameorder']) : ""; //name of product ordered
        print $productquantity = isset($_POST['productqty']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productqty']) : ""; //Quantity of product ordered
        $product_name     = explode(",", $productnameorder); //explode product name and pack size
        $finalArray       = array();
        $product_quantity = explode(",", $productquantity);
        foreach ($product_name as $data) {
            print_r($product_name);

            $innerArray        = array();
            $product           = explode(" ", $data);
            $productName       = $product[0]; //product name
            $productSize       = $product[1]; //pack size
            //get product id,price from pm_productmaster_cstm and pp_productpricing_cstm respectively
            $sqlProductDetails = "SELECT pm.id_c as id, pm.`status_c` AS pmStatus, pp.price_c, pp.`status_c` AS ppStatus,pp.id_c as pricingID 
    FROM `pm_productmaster_cstm` AS pm LEFT JOIN `pp_productpricing_cstm` AS pp ON pp.pm_productmaster_id_c = pm.id_c
    WHERE pm.`productname_c` = '{$productName}' AND pm.`numdays_c` = '{$productSize}' AND pm.`status_c` = '1'  AND pp.`status_c`= '1' ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: Kindly do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and will be removed from the current and future versions. Either use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: print $data and give that array.

Comment: @Anuradha What does `print_r($product)` give you?

Comment: Hello parveen thanks for quick response. print_r($product) gives me 

Array
(
    [0] => 
)

Comment: @Anuradha I am **Praveen**, not Parveen or Pravin. Anyways, the variable has only one index `0`. So try changing it to `$productSize = $product[0];`. Arrays are zero-based indices.

Comment: @Anuradha Let me know if the solution solves. Else, let me know in the comments.

Comment: @Anuradha Consider being respectful by keeping the conversation going or ending the conversation in a better way and accepting the answers that work for you, in this question as well as the previous questions you have asked. Do not run away once you have received the right answer. You might be banned from asking future questions then.

Answer (score 2):

According to the OP, the output of `print_r($product)` gives:

```
Array (
    [0] =>
)
```

So the problem caused is because of array index out of bounds. The array indices are **zero based**. So, the solution for getting the first value of the array would be using:

```
$productSize = $product[0];
```